# Adding and extracting image metadata

Tags: opencv, opencv3.0

- I have a computer that is recording video and storing it.
  Is there a way to add metadata to every frame? like location, camera orientation.
- after recording the video i upload it to my server.
  Is there a way to extract the metadata that i saved for each frame?

My solution write know is to save separately a metadata xml file with frame number and its metadata.

So is there a way to save the Metadata in the frames header or something like this (that i wont need anther file).

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This will likely depend on a few things, but as far as I can foresee, you may indeed have to store any metadata in an xml or relational database or some such file, seperately. The thing to do is look at the specification for your video format and look at what kind of video stream is permitted, and then see if this coincides with some image format. In other words, if you manage to find a video format that stores each frame as a jpeg with the metadata included, and you dont mind working/converting to/from it, then you just need to write a program to do what you want to the individual frames.

HOWEVER this would seem like an unlikely outcome, as most modern video stream formats probably come with some relatively unique compression algorithms that condense the video data in such a way that individual frames dont actually exist in the data, and, rather, are "built" during viewing/editing/etc. Even if this is not the case, and the video is stored similarly to a gif where each frame is technically independent of the last, metadata is likely stripped in order to compress the data what little it can.

Short answer: Look around and see if any video specifications offer what you are looking for but manage your expectations.